# My 2008 Volvo xc70 dashboard shows steering wheel locked, car will not start, what can I do?

Tags: volvo

My 08 xc70 is showing an image of a steering and pad lock, car won't start, what can I do?

Comment: And you can turn the steering wheel or not? These are the ones with the electric steering lock, right?

Comment: Is there a chance that the steering wheel was locked while there was tension on the wheel and now it can't unlock?  Does slightly turning the wheel help?

Comment: If it's a keyless start how's the transponder battery?

Comment: This might be interesting to you. It seems lots of people are having the issue.       http://www.volvo-forums.com/t11748-steering-lock-quotplease-turn-wheelquot.htm

Answer (score 2):

That's a common issue with the steering column lock (SCL) on these cars. The SCL would need to be replaced, and this requires someone with a VIDA subscription as it requires a software download to the replacement module.

As a temporary workaround, try turning the wheel all the way either CW or CCW, hold it there, and only then attempt to start the car while holding the steering wheel. This workaround worked for some people.

When you have this fault, it's also possible that the steering wheel might lock while the car is in motion: understandably, that's dangerous. Should it happen make sure to file an NHTSA report!

Comment: Should it happen while in motion, OP may not have a chance to report it to the NHTSA!

Comment: @MooseLucifer Very true...